# asp mvc list ecommerce product with dynamically changing specifications

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, e-commerce

i am trying to develop product details page for eCommerce site, say we list some products in a view , now when users clicks in a product he is taken product details view to show product specifications, with add to cart, reviews etc , but here product specification changes dynamically for every product , **example:**

**Clothing Product:**

`Size` : 40

**Mobile Product:**

`Operating System` : Android

now i dont want the specification name operating system in a clothing product and vice versa.

so i researched about this and found [this](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/62271/database-design-for-ecommerce-website-with-multiple-products-having-huge-specifi) and [this](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/24636/product-attribute-list-design-pattern) post's . But [some](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/870808/entity-attribute-value-database-vs-strict-relational-model-ecommerce-question) folk's comment saying `Entity Attribute Value is not good practice` ,

so can anyone help me choose best and easy design pattern to list product details with changing specifications in asp mvc, i am new to this.

Any help would be great.

Answer (score 1):

EAV has several downsides:

- The database layer can't force attribute names to be correct, so you have to do it in code
- Search performance is slow if you're filtering on values in the EAV table
- Performance is also slow if you try to join other tables based on the values in the EAV table

But if you need a flexible and dynamic set of attributes and you **don't** need to search or join by the attribute values, EAV is a good solution.

Comment: I know this is very late comment, I have already used EAV model, is there any best alternative which can be searched for, what kind of model does amazon etc use to search products by specifications ?

Comment: Also I can see some product details page which has product features with images , with stylish typography design and buttons for single product, I thing we can use  wysiwyg html editor and save in SQL as `nvarchar(max)`, and decode the html later, Am i correct ?