# c#: 'Inline' remove the decimal part, and then seperate the remained value by cama seperator

Tags: c#, string, razor

I want to show `12345.678` as `12,345` in my .cshtml file using Razor.
Is there any **INLINE** solution?

When I use:

```
<td>  @(myValue != null ? myValue.ToString().Substring(myValue.ToString().IndexOf(".") + 1).ToString("#,##0") : '-')</td>
```

The error message is:

> The best overloaded method match for '`string.ToString(System.IFormatProvider)`' has some invalid arguments

And for:

```
<td>@(myValue != null ? myValue.ToString().Format("{0:0}", myValue).ToString("#,##0") : '-')</td>
```

The error message is:

> Member '`string.Format(string, object)`' cannot be accessed with an instance reference;

Comment: what's the type of `myValue`?

Comment: it's long (Int64)

Comment: how can `12345.678` be `long`?

Comment: thank you it was another bug! myValue= Convert.ToInt64(ViewBag.MyVal)

Comment: you're welcome. you should probably edit your question for it to be more clear: specify the type of `myValue`, it's actual value, how it is being passed to the view, and how you want it to appear in the view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the second one, just as the error says, you are trying to invoke `.Format()` on an instance of a string, but `.Format()` is a `static` method.  So instead of this:

```
myValue.ToString().Format("{0:0}", myValue).ToString("#,##0")
```

You'd do something like this:

```
string.Format("{0:0}", myValue).ToString("#,##0")
```

Note that `myValue` is passed as an argument to the `static` method, you don't call the method on the object itself.

As an aside, in general when you're working in any sort of MVC (or MVVM, etc.) pattern and finding yourself trying to do even remotely complex inline code in a view, what you're really looking for is to add a calculated property to your model and then just bind to that property.  The logic belongs in the view model, not the view itself.

Answer (score 2):

Based on the comments in the OP, it looks like you're passing a `double` to the view via the `ViewBag`, converting it to `long`, and then attempting to format it inline?

Essentially:

- Converting `12345.678D` to `long`, thus becoming `12345`
- Formatting `12345` to `12,345`

This should work:

```
<td>@string.Format("{0:n0}", Convert.ToInt64(ViewBag.MyVal))</td>
```

Bear in mind that as already pointed out by [@David](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44629466/4302070), you're better off passing a viewmodel back to the view as opposed to `ViewBag`, with `myValue` being a property of the viewmodel itself. You can see how to implement viewmodels in my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31855820/4302070).

That being said, at the very least, I would abstract the logic away by creating my own class (let's call it `MyHtmlHelper`) which extends [`HtmlHelper`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.htmlhelper(v=vs.118).aspx):

```
namespace System.Web.Mvc.Html
{
    public static class MyHtmlHelper
    {
        public static string DoubleToFormattedLong(this HtmlHelper html, double myValue)
        {
            var longValue = Convert.ToInt64(myValue);
            return string.Format("{0:n0}", longValue);
        }
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
<td>@Html.DoubleToFormattedLong((double)ViewBag.MyVal)</td>
```

I'm not performing any validation whatsoever in my examples, but validation should ideally also be in place.

Answer (score 0):

you can extend function for the integer or other numeric data type like this

```
 namespace Utility
 {
      public static class Global
      {
           public static string DecimalSepeartor(this int s)
           {
                NumberFormatInfo nfi = new CultureInfo("en-US", false).NumberFormat;
                return (s.ToString("N", nfi));
           }
      }
 }
```

then you can use this extended function as bellow

```
@using Utility
//
//
//

<div> 
     @Model.Amount.DecimalSepeartor() 
</div>
```